# Vue created can not force to run non async

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous

I have a Vue.js application and on the `/callback` route I am trying to have it do a few things. So far I am not having any luck with it because I am seeing things run async. I understand that it is normally how Vue/Javascript works however I am trying to force it to not be async.

The main issue I am having is sometimes the `this.$store...` are running before the items are set. This is an issue because of how things run on other Vuex actions. Mainly the `getCompany` one requires the `loadToken` one to complete as it is pulling the values from the local storage which is being set above.

I don't want to change this and how it works because of how the Vue router is set up to pull the token from local storage on each page reload. This token is used to connect to the backend so it needs to be pulled from local storage each reload as I don't want a user to log in just because they reload the page.

Code:

```
created() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', this.$auth.token)
      localStorage.setItem('user_data', JSON.stringify(this.$auth.user))
      // Load company data
      this.$store.dispatch('loadToken')
      this.$store.dispatch('getCompany')
      if(this.$auth == null || this.$auth.id_token['https://hello.io/account_signup_type/is_new']) {
        this.$router.push('/setup')
      } else {
        // Load user data from Auth0
        
        // Go to chat page
        this.$router.push('/chat')
      }
    }, 500)
  }
```

edit main.js code

```
import { Auth0Plugin } from '@/auth/auth0-plugin';

// Install the authentication plugin
Vue.use(Auth0Plugin, {
  domain,
  clientId,
  audience,
  onRedirectCallback: (appState) => {
    router.push(
      appState && appState.targetUrl
        ? appState.targetUrl
        : window.location.pathname,
    );
  },
});
```

auth0-plugin

```
/**
 *  External Modules
 */

 import Vue from 'vue';
 import createAuth0Client from '@auth0/auth0-spa-js';
 
 /**
  *  Vue.js Instance Definition
  */
 
 let instance;
 
 export const getInstance = () => instance;
 
 /**
  *  Vue.js Instance Initialization
  */
 
 export const useAuth0 = ({
   onRedirectCallback = () =>
     window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.pathname),
   redirectUri = `${window.location.origin}/callback`,
   ...pluginOptions
 }) => {
   if (instance) return instance;
 
   instance = new Vue({
     data() {
       return {
         auth0Client: null,
         isLoading: true,
         isAuthenticated: false,
         user: {},
         error: null,
         token: null,
         id_token: null
       };
     },
     methods: {
       async handleRedirectCallback() {
         this.isLoading = true;
         try {
           await this.auth0Client.handleRedirectCallback();
           this.user = await this.auth0Client.getUser();
           this.isAuthenticated = true;
         } catch (error) {
           this.error = error;
         } finally {
           this.isLoading = false;
         }
       },
 
       loginWithRedirect(options) {
         return this.auth0Client.loginWithRedirect(options);
       },
 
       logout(options) {
         return this.auth0Client.logout(options);
       },
 
       getTokenSilently(o) {
         return this.auth0Client.getTokenSilently(o);
       },

       getIdTokenClaims(o) {
        return this.auth0Client.getIdTokenClaims(o);
       }
     },
 
     async created() {
       this.auth0Client = await createAuth0Client({
         ...pluginOptions,
        //  responseType: 'id_token',
         domain: pluginOptions.domain,
         client_id: pluginOptions.clientId,
         audience: pluginOptions.audience,
         redirect_uri: redirectUri,
       });
 
       try {
         if (
           window.location.search.includes('code=') &&
           window.location.search.includes('state=')
         ) {
           const { appState } = await this.auth0Client.handleRedirectCallback();
 
           onRedirectCallback(appState);
         }
       } catch (error) {
         this.error = error;
       } finally {
         this.isAuthenticated = await this.auth0Client.isAuthenticated();
         this.user = await this.auth0Client.getUser();
         this.$auth.getTokenSilently().then(token => this.token = token)
         this.$auth.getIdTokenClaims().then(id_token => this.id_token = id_token)
         this.isLoading = false;
       }
     },
   });
 
   return instance;
 };
 
 /**
  *  Vue.js Plugin Definition
  */
 
 export const Auth0Plugin = {
   install(Vue, options) {
     Vue.prototype.$auth = useAuth0(options);
   },
 };
```

edit - updated router.beforeEach

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  const auth = getInstance()
  if(to.path == '/callback' && auth != null) {
    console.log('Callback')
    console.log(`Token: ${auth.token}`)
    console.log(`User: ${JSON.stringify(auth.user)}`)
    localStorage.setItem('token', auth.token)
    localStorage.setItem('user_data', JSON.stringify(auth.user))
    await store.dispatch('loadToken')
    await store.dispatch('getCompany')
    return next()
  }
  if(to.path != '/login' && to.path != '/setup') {
    await store.dispatch('loadToken')
    await store.dispatch('getCompany')
    .then(() => {
      return next()
    }) 
  } else {
    return next()
  }
})
```

edit - adding guide that I followed from Auth0 to get the code I have now - mostly

https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-vue-user-authentication/

Comment: Did you tried `async created` and `await this.$store.dispatch etc...` for each vuex action?

Comment: You can't force asynchronous things to NOT be asynchronous. The mistake is that you ignore promises that dispatch returns. Also this code belongs to router beforeRouteEnter/Update hook or global beforeEnter, certainly not created.

Comment: @kissu That doesn't work because some of the stuff is not promise based and await will not work.

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm ignoring the promises dispatch returns because I don't need them. As for doing this elsewhere, those is only needed on the first page it hits after login so no need to run it every time before it hits a route. That would be a waste of time and resources for the end user.

Comment: Just checked and `beforeRouteEnter` doesn't give access to `this` which is needed for my code to work so that is out.

Comment: You don't need to have everything promise based for it to work. And yep, you can access the Vue instance on some router guards, it's just not `this` but `vm`.

Comment: @joshk132 You have this problem because you didn't chain them and this resulted in race condition. Consider checking how promises work and what purpose promise pattern serves. As a rule of thumb, every promise needs to be chained, unless proven otherwise. In Enter an instance is available as `next(vm => ...)`, but any way, you don't use an instance here. Everything with $ are global deps and they can be imported directly, e.g. a store. If you don't need the logic to run every time, you can run it on a condition. Global logic like auth belongs to router.beforeEnter, not a specific comp.

Comment: @EstusFlask Can you please provide an example of what you mean? I'm not sure I follow exactly, I could have it run in router.beforeEnter but I think that is not something I think will work out. So I could do say a condition on if the token exists in local storage but what happens when that expires? Or the user logs back in, I want to store a new token and user_data. If I did a condition on it then it probably won't work or at least I can't think of a condition which would cause it to only run on the first login where the /callback is hit.

Comment: Just tried a few things and seems I can't access `this.$auth` inside my `router.beforeEach` Suggestions on how I can access it? See edit in OP for code in main.js which brings in `this.$auth`

Comment: What is auth/auth0-plugin exactly? You have to be able to import `auth`. You don't need `this` to access global values, it's a remnant of non-modular ES5.

Comment: @EstusFlask Added an edit to the page with the auth plugin code. All of this code for the auth plugin and bringing it into main.js is from auth0 docs/guides.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is race condition because `dispatch` calls return promises that weren't chained before accessing the result of their work.

A good practice is to chain every promise, unless proven other wise.

The code that `created` contains actually belongs to the router in general because authentication logic is application-wide.

It's unnecessary to access global dependencies on `this` component instance. This is done for historical reasons because Vue originally was used in non-modular environment. In order to use outside components, global dependencies such as `store` need to be explicitly imported. In case this cannot be done, this needs to be fixed.

In this case `auth` instance is available through `getInstance`. In case the authentication shouldn't be done on each navigation, this needs to be done on condition, e.g.:

```
import { getInstance } from '.../auth';
import store from '.../store';
...
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
   const auth = getInstance();

   if (...) {
     ...
     await store.dispatch('loadToken')
     await store.dispatch('getCompany') 
     ...
     next('/setup')
     ...
   } else {
     next()
   }
 })
```

`getInstance` doesn't serve a good purpose because it just exposes a variable. Instead, `instance` could be exported and imported directly, the behaviour would be the same due to how ES modules work.

Also global store already holds application logic and commonly used to handle authentication, including local storage operations.

Comment: Thanks, so for the last comment about the global store handling the local storage operations. Where is that in my code? I don't see it at all which is why I had to do it myself. 

As for doing it inside the router.beforeEach, you have an if statement but what goes in that? Your example code makes it seem like I would just reuse the existing if statement, should I not be checking for auth to exist or something? Also, you have imported the auth in a different way than I have it, should I be making changes? Why would I reimport the auth as something different? my router.beforeEach is in main.js

Comment: I mean that `localStorage.setItem`, `auth`, etc could be used inside a store, so auth logic would be abstracted away and you'd won't deal with low-level details in places where you consume it. "what goes in that?" - who knows? You said that you don't need to run it  on each navigation, this is what this condition is for. If you want to check auth state then check auth state there. You need to import `getInstance` in order to call it, that's it. If you need to import `Auth0Plugin` as well then do this. They aren't interchangeable.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, so in my main.js edit I import that auth plugin/file. Can I reuse that? As for the global store storing the auth logic... I don't see where you are saying it does? The auth store has the regsiter and the get user stuff but that's it. Nothing global or anything like that. I also don't really handle a lot of auth stuff so not sure what you are thinking of. Your answer seems to make some sense but a lot of it seems a bit off from how I understand my code. Based off the code provided in the OP/edits can you explain where you are getting that stuff is already stored in local?

Comment: So figured out you meant the getinstance as a different import. Tried that and checked values on `auth.token` and `auth.user` and came back as `null` and `{}` respectively. Seems like however that getinstance works it doesn't have anything of use for me in it.

Comment: I just added another edit showing my current router.beforeEach